# real-time-match or matchmaking in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, multiplayer

I'm working in a multiplayer game using swift and firebase .

I'm trying to understand how **matchmaking** or **real-time-match** work.

So I just want to know what methods should I be using ? And is there a difference between **Game Center**  and **Firebase** methods ?

Comment: This question is unclear as we can't answer what method you should be using as you've not told us what you need methods for. Also, Game Center and Firebase are completely unrelated. GameKit is an API to handle player and game interactions whereas Firebase is a real-time NoSQL database. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)> update your question with better and more info and we'll take a look.